# How to display json response from the stream to the console

Tags: java, json, jira, jira-rest-api

I'm trying to access all the jira issues using the jira-rest-api url in the following way:

```
URL url;

url = new URL("http://ficcjira.xyz.com/rest/api/2/search?jql=project=ABC&fields=timespent");

    URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

    String auth = "username" + ":" + "password";
    byte[] authBytes = auth.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    String encodedAuth = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(authBytes);
    conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + encodedAuth);

    try (InputStream responseStream = conn.getInputStream()) {

        //JsonElement element = new JsonParser(stream).parse(responseStream);

        // To read response as a string:
        MimeType contentType = new MimeType(conn.getContentType());
        String charset = contentType.getParameter("charset");
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        String response =
            new Scanner(responseStream, charset).useDelimiter("\\Z").next();
```

I get a response from the url as a JSON response. What do I do next to display the response to the console?

UPDATE:

Geting Null pointer exception when trying to do System.out.printn(response);

Comment: Don't change the meaning of your question, when you already have answers for the original question. If you have a new question, then create a new post.

Comment: @Tom I was told to update my question in the below comment.

Comment: Updating the question doesn't include removing the old one. You may append additional information, but since you have a _new_ question, create a new post instead.

Comment: @Tom A bit harsh, the questioner was responding to another answer.

Answer (score 0):

`System.out.println(response)` : to print to console

And also you can avoid boilerplate code by using the libraries. For example, you can replace all your code with below single line.

```
String response = IOUtils.toString(new URL("http://ficcjira.xyz.com/rest/api/2/search?jql=project=ABC&fields=timespent"));
```

`IOUtils` is part of apache commons.

Comment: Yes I 'm doing that but I get this error: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at javax.activation.MimeType.parse(MimeType.java:97)
 at javax.activation.MimeType.<init>(MimeType.java:63)
 at TimeLogged.main(TimeLogged.java:51)

Comment: @Ramya Please update your question with actual issue which is NPE.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use a System.out.print(); of the string response you streammed

Comment: Yes I 'm doing that but I get this error: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at javax.activation.MimeType.parse(MimeType.java:97)
 at javax.activation.MimeType.<init>(MimeType.java:63)
 at TimeLogged.main(TimeLogged.java:51)

Comment: Try to use a Logger class